# Why is "assert 211 == 211" failing?

Tags: python, string-formatting

This fails:

```
train_data = pd.concat([train_cancelled, train_not_cancelled]).as_matrix()

mat_col_size = int((num_days * 3) + 1)

assert isinstance(mat_col_size, int), "mat_col_size is not an int"
assert isinstance(train_data.shape[1], int), "train_data.shape[1] is not an int"

assert train_data.shape[1] == mat_col_size, \
    "Number of columns in train data must be 'num_fetaures + 1 = {0:d}' (label) but is '{0:1}'." \
        .format(mat_col_size, train_data.shape[1])
```

It will print:

```
AssertionError: Number of columns in train data must be 'num_fetaures + 1 = 211' (label) but is '211'.
```

My question is: How many different things can go wrong and cause this to fail because I simply don't find the issue or the reason why my code does not make the third `assert`!

Comment: can you post an example of the training data? maybe with all the colums but just a few rows

Comment: at the very least, can you show us the output of `type(train_data.shape[1])`? it might have type `numpy.int64` instead of `int`

Comment: for what it's worth, i can't reproduce with `assert pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]).as_matrix().shape[1] == 3`

Comment: @ssdecontrol I'd expect `numpy.int64` to implement comparison with vanilla integers correctly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I think we can close this as a typo.

Comment: @PM2Ring I agree and just for the record: *facepalm* .. Voting for close.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski i've had it fail in Django's `django.test.TestCase.assertEqual`, but that might also have stricter type checking than just `==`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format string is selecting the first argument twice by using positional selector `0` twice. You're not actually seeing the value of `train_data.shape[1]`, it's printing the value of `mat_col_size` in both cases. I think you meant:

```
"Number of columns in train data must be 'num_fetaures + 1 = {0:d}' (label) but is '{1}'."
```

or, assuming it's Py 2.7+, you could simplify to just:

```
"Number of columns in train data must be 'num_fetaures + 1 = {}' (label) but is '{}'."
```

allowing it to automatically match up placeholders to positional arguments without specifying numbers explicitly (and there is no reason to specify the `d` format unit either; it's not `printf`, it'll stringify on its own).

Comment: *facepalm* ....

Comment: @displayname: You at least came up with an interesting hit, `{0:1}` at first glance could easily be read incorrectly when you assume you're just providing sequential positional arguments. As it happens, it's really just padding an argument that formats to the empty string out to a single space (and leaving all other arguments unchanged), but it's more subtle than the simplest case. This sort of problem is why I _always_ avoid numbering my positional format units unless I actually need to reuse one.

Comment: I think I will keep that in mind for the future :D but the most evil thing is simple blindness that one gets after a while programming.